# "Sign in to Google Assistant to make it yours" - but I don't want to!

Tags: google-account, google, google-assistant

I don't use a Google Account on my phone; nor do I use Google Assistant. However, for the past few... weeks, I guess, my phone keeps getting into a screen which tells me I must log into a Google Account to use Google Assistant. I think it happens mainly/only when I turn on the monitor after it's been off due to idling.

Can I get rid of that notification somehow? Or maybe my phone not try whatever it is it's trying?

Note: Xiaomi MI 9 SE phone (Android v11, MIUI Global 12.5)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the "Google" app which hosts Assistant and that should completely disable all it's related functionality.

If, for whatever reason, you want to still keep using that app, you can try to set "Default Digital assistant" app to "None". It should be under Apps section in Android settings.

Comment: How can I disable it?